# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on enhanced for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out part of an assignment and I have been beating my head against a wall for some time now. I'm trying to transcribe DNA sequences to RNA sequences. I am, however, getting an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. I am new to using enhanced for loops to iterate so my mistake may be hiding in there somewhere. It doesn't occur until the if statement parameters have been met.

```
private String dnaToRNA(String input) {

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
    for (char a : arr) {
        if (a == 'T') {
            arr[a] ='U';

        }
    }   
     for (char a : arr) {
        if (a == 'A'){
            b.append ('U');
        }

        else if (a == 'U') {
            b.append('A');
        }

        else if (a == 'C') {
            b.append('G');
        }   

        else if (a == 'G') {
            b.append('C');
        }   

    }   


    return b.reverse().toString();
}

}

   public void transcribe(int pos1) {

    if (pos1 > linkedList.size()) {
        System.out.println("Position selected out of range");
        return;
    }
    if (linkedList.get(pos1) != null && isValidDNA(linkedList.get(pos1))) {
        linkedList.set(pos1, dnaToRNA(linkedList.get(pos1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `if (pos1 > linkedList.size())` with `if (pos1 >= linkedList.size())` as indexes are 0-based in java

Comment: I get the same error message if I do that actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the statement `arr[a] ='U';`

The problem is that `char` is represented as an `int` internally and `'T'` equals 84 hence you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
You need to iterate over it with a traditional counter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 'T') {
        arr[i] ='U';
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it...Thanks alot! I was wondering if it wasn't a problem with using that iterator. THanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You want 1 less than size , so : `if (pos1 >= linkedList.size()) {`.

When `pos1 == linkedList.size()` it will be out of bounds